# Why isn't internal pull-down resistor working on STM32F411CEU6 (Black Pill Board)?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, microcontroller

I am trying to configure the STM32F411CEU6 onboard button (PA0), but cannot configure it to use the internal pull-down resistor. My current setup allows it to trigger an interrupt when using a pull-up resistor, but when I change it to a pull-down resistor it no longer works. I would appreciate if anyone could guide me on what I did wrong, and could clarify my understanding of the process. I am using the STM32 Standard Peripheral Library. I have put my GPIO initialization code below.

```
// enable clocks for the the KEY button (PA0) GPIO and 
//  the system configuration controller (SYSCFG) for GPIO interrupts
RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_SYSCFG, ENABLE);

// initialize the GPIO pin, PA0, with an internal Pull-Down resistor
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_Button_InitStructure = { 
        .GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0,
        .GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN,
        .GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_DOWN         /* works with GPIO_PuPd_UP... */
};
GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_Button_InitStructure);

/* ... Other interrupt enabling configuration stuff that is known to work here... */
```

Comment: Maybe your external interrupt edge configuration is wrong? Or it may be related the external hardware connections and/or configurations.

Comment: Please add more information on the hardware setup you're using, if possible. How is the button exactly connected to pin `PA0`?

Comment: @Tagli The interrupt edge is configured to trigger at both rising and/or falling edges. It works fine when using a pull up resistor and I can see it being triggered via the debugger then. What other external hardware connection / configuration could be causing this?

Comment: @rel The STM32 board I am using (Black Pill) has an onboard button labeled KEY which is connected to pin PA0 as per the pin out diagram shown [here](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/2.5.0/boards/arm/blackpill_f411ce/doc/index.html).

Comment: @ZetaCentauri That information (the board) needs to be in the question, not in the comments. STM32F411CEU6 is an MCU, on its own it has no button. Judging from the answer, it is an electronics question, not a software issue.

Comment: Although you have an answer here, understanding the external electronics is better asked at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ZetaCentauri In that case, the pin's voltage will not change when the button is pressed, like @Tagli already answered below. It will always stay LOW at 0 V, hence no interrupt can/should happen. (If you want to test the behavior with different GPIO configurations, you could use another unused pin on the board (e.g. `PA1`) and check if an external interrupt can be triggered there on the rising edge, with internal or external pull-down resistor, and test things out on a breadboard...)

Comment: @Clifford Ah I see! Apologies, wasn't sure where to post the question. I will also update the question to contain the specific board I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user push button on your black pill board is connected between **PA0** and **GND**. It makes no sense to configure PA0 with pull-down configuration. In this case, pushing the button won't affect the state of the PA0 pin; it was *logic 0* before the push and remain at *logic 0* during and after the push. Obviously, the the hardware and software can't detect this push.

**Edit:**

Unlike the older blue pill boards, the schematic of the black pill boards is harder to find on internet. I was able to find it on their [official Github repo](https://github.com/WeActTC/MiniSTM32F4x1/tree/master/HDK). However, connecting push buttons to **GND** and pulling-up uC pins to *logic 1* using either internal or external pull-up resistors is a common practice, so I'm not surprised that black pill board follows the same tradition.

Comment: Awesome! Just. found the schematics and was able to confirm. Thank you!